# File Upload in React native using ImagePicker and s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, react-native-image-picker

I am trying to upload the image from the device to s3 directly. I am able to read the image metadata and sending it to the server to generate the pre-signed url for the aws s3. I also have the pre-signed url to with I want to upload the file/image using `axios` but somehow the image/file is not getting uploaded. Here is my code.

Image data (read by the ImagePicker)

```
data: "" // image raw data
fileName: "acx.jpg"
fileSize: ""
uri: ""
path: ""
```

Code for sending the selected image to aws s3.

```
const options = { headers: { 'Content-Type': fileType}};
axios.put(res.data.signedRequest, data , options);
```

I'm getting the following respose.

```
res = {
  config: 
  data: ""
  status: 200
  StatusText: undefined
  ...
}
```

So what should I pass as data in the `axios` request?

Comment: did u find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you explored this [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-aws3)  ? It would make the process a lot easier. You could then try

```
 upload = () => {
  const file = {
    uri: this.state.imageuri,
    name: acx.jpg,
    type: "image/jpeg"
  };
  const options = {
    keyPrefix: "ts/",
    bucket: "celeb-c4u",
    region: "eu-west-1",
    accessKey: "AKIAI2NHLR7A5W2R3OLA",
    secretKey: "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",
    successActionStatus: 201
  };
  return RNS3.put(file, options)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.status !== 201)
        throw new Error("Failed to upload image to S3");
      else {
        console.log(
          "Successfully uploaded image to s3. s3 bucket url: ",
          response.body.postResponse.location
        );
        this.setState({
          url: response.body.postResponse.location
        });
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};
```

Comment: I know about this plugin. But I want to upload via signed URL since I dont want to use `accessKey` and `secretKey` in the front-end/mobile app

Comment: you could set them to environment variables that would be configured in your build process.